# (LeetCode question: 139. Word Break) Java Solution Timeout -- Backtracking Solution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

The link to the question: [139. Word Break](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/)
The solution below can not passed all the test cases and lead to timeout. I want to use backtracking to solve this question, however it seems that it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?
Besides, the solution here its time complexity is O(2^n + n^2). How can I optimize it so that it can pass all test cases? Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

```
class Solution {
    boolean found;
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        backtrack(s, wordDict, 0);
        return found;
    }
    public void backtrack(String s, List<String> wordDict, int index){
        if(found == true) return;
        if(index == s.length()){
            found = true;
            return;
        }
        for(int len = 1; index + len <= s.length(); len++){
            String prefix = s.substring(index, index + len);
            if(wordDict.contains(prefix)){
                backtrack(s, wordDict, index + len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: the real answer isn't to ask other people to identify the errors in your code. The answer is: A) you enable yourself to better understand what your code is ACTUALLY doing, for example by adding print/log statements and B) you write tests yourself. Tons of them. You step back, you think about basic, simply tests, about tests that expose this or that special condition, and so on. And ideally, you write them upfront. Research "TDD" for that part. Such algorithmic problems are PERFECT for training your "lets write tests" skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that reply my question!! I fixed and optimized my solution with memoization. Now, the solution can pass all the test cases on leetcode.

```
class Solution {
    int[] memo;
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        memo = new int[s.length()];
        Arrays.fill(memo, -1);
        return dp(s, wordDict, 0);
    }
    public boolean dp(String s, List<String> wordDict, int i){
        if(i == s.length()) return true;
        if(memo[i] != -1) return memo[i] == 0? false: true;
        for(String word: wordDict){
            int len = word.length();
            if(i + len > s.length()) continue;
            if(!word.equals(s.substring(i, i + len))) continue;
            if(dp(s, wordDict, i + len)){
                memo[i] = 1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        memo[i] = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- Trying at *all* indices and all *lengths* to match *all* words is doing way too much. Many of those tests will never succeed. For instance, if the list of words only has words of sizes 3 and 4, it makes no sense to still compare with them for lengths that are greater than 4. Imagine the processing when the string input has a length of 1000.
- When two words have been matched to get to index 10, but nothing works to cover for the remaining part of `s`, you'll backtrack and try other words. If you then happen to find other words to lead up to index 10, it makes no sense to try to cover for the remaining part *again*. It is already known that it will not work. So you should register the index from where an attempt was not successful, so that if ever you arrive at that index again, you'll not redo the recursive search. You can use a boolean array for this, with a boolean for each index.
- Instead of returning when `found` is already true, break out of the loop when `found` is true, avoiding any further recursive calls.
- Using an instance member `found` is fine, but the test framework will run your code on the same instance of `Solution`, so that the value of `found` is not reset to `false` between two tests. You must reset `found` to `false` every time the function is called. I would however suggest to make your function *return* that boolean value, so you don't need that instance member at all.

Here is a spoiler solution using the above remarks:

> `class Solution {
>     String s;
>     List wordDict;
>     boolean fails[];
>
>     public boolean wordBreak(String s, List wordDict) {
>         this.s = s;
>         this.wordDict = wordDict;
>         fails = new boolean[s.length()];
>         return backtrack(0);
>     }
>
>     public boolean backtrack(int index){
>         if (index == s.length()) return true;
>         if (fails[index]) return false; // Already tried here
>         for (String word : wordDict) {
>             if (s.regionMatches(index, word, 0, word.length())) {
>                 if (backtrack(index + word.length())) return true;
>             }
>         }
>         fails[index] = true;
>         return false;
>     }
> }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your solution can be easily noticed by adding a print statement.

```
public void backtrack(String s, List<String> wordDict, int index){
    System.out.println(String.format("Calling function with '%s', index=%d", s, index));
    ....
```

Here if you execute example test case

```
Input: s = "catsandog", wordDict = ["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"]
```

You will notice:

```
1. Calling function with 'catsandog', index=0
2. Calling function with 'catsandog', index=3
3. Calling function with 'catsandog', index=7
4. Calling function with 'catsandog', index=4
5. Calling function with 'catsandog', index=7
```

As you can see (print statements 3 and 5) same execution is happening two times. Now imagine this with a really long answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying me so quickly! I've went through my code before... So do you mean that my code logic is fine and all I need to do is try to optimize my code? How can I optimize it specifically?

Comment: You need to avoid duplicated function calls. It is what is making your execution so slow. Also I will recommend using String.startsWith function.  If you are looking for a problem solution please search in youtube/online there are many  good there.